# Where did this DC-DC converter board come from?

Tags: identification

I have, in a collection of long-ago purchased parts for making a nixie tube clock, this small circuit board. I'm pretty sure it is some sort of DC-DC transformer used to step voltage up to nixie tube level. I also faintly remember ordering it from a very-90s looking plain HTML webpage. Searching for any visible markings on the device yields nothing pointing in the right direction.

The device has 2 rows of 6 pins with the text `XFMRS 1363-T1 1734` written on top of what appears to be a copper wire coil.

I'm specifically looking for a pinout/circuit diagram and, if possible, the place it could have been purchased from, likely around 2017-2018.

[image: device - top]
[image: device - bottom]
[image: device - angle]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [First hit](https://www.shop-tes.com/1363-hvps-vertical/) when googleing "1363 nixie". Has a pinout in the description.

Comment: @Unimportant  I guess I didn't know the right search terms. The answer is yours if you're so inclined

Comment: And a [datasheet](https://www.tayloredge.com/storefront/SmartNixie/DataSheets/Datasheet_1363-1364.pdf).